# Gnome-Screenshot error in Ubuntu GNOME 13.10

Tags: command-line, gnome, shortcut-keys, screenshot

I recently installed Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 (it came with GNOME 3.8, but I replaced it by GNOME 3.10) and after a few problems, the only one I couldn't solve was the screenshot problem.

When I press the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> key, nothing happens. No sound, no nothing. When I execute it via Terminal by writing "Gnome-Screenshot", it does work and saves a screenshot in my Pictures folder.

I have already tried to re-install the program, but still didn't work. I also tried to create a shortcut with this command line, but still nothing happened. I tried to replace the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> key by another one, just for make sure the problem wasn't in the key, and it still failed.

Can anyone help me?

[image: via terminal]

Comment: How did you try assigning the command to `PrtSc`? Through the gnome-settings?

Comment: Yes. I disabled the PrtSc key as the default screenshot key in the original settings and added a new command in the custom shortcuts tab.

Comment: @snoop: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/370672/revisions)?  thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be an entire section of the keyboard settings designated to screenshot:

(Run `gnome-control-center keyboard shortcuts`)

[image: Keyboard Settings]

If that fails, gnome-screenshot itself has a control window

(Run `gnome-screenshot --interactive`)

[image: Gnome Screenshot]

Using Gnome 3.8.