# Change gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04

Tags: gnome, configuration, gconf, dconf

Configuring with `dconf` or `gconf` as suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114429/default-save-directory-for-gnome-screenshot) worded on Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 (I tried and succeeded). But does NOT work on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.

How to change `auto-save-directory` of `gnome-screenshot` on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04?

Answer (score 15):

#### Edit

after reading this [article](https://marteydodoo.com/writing/2013/12/15/saving-screenshots-different-directory-gnome-3/) and this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370672/gnome-screenshot-error-in-ubuntu-gnome-13-10) it seems like in **Ubuntu-Gnome 14.04 (gnome 3.10)** the screenshots with Keyboard shortcuts eg:<kbd>Print</kbd> are handle by the shell *(gnome-settings-daemon media-keys)* saving the files to *~/Pictures* and not by the gnome-screenshot application.

I have installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 to test it.

**1)** I set the auto-save-directory to */tmp*:

- `gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory '/tmp'`

**2)** I disable the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Print</kbd> and I created a new one to run the **gnome-screenshot** command with the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> . Then I pressed the new shortcut and the screenshot appears in the */tmp* directory.

[image]

[image]

[image]

So, set the **auto-save-directory** value works for gnome-screenshot, but to solve this issue you can try to disable the default keyboard shortcuts for Screenshots and create new ones but running the gnome-screenshot command.

#### gnome-screenshots command examples:

Whole screen: `gnome-screenshot`
Grab a window: `screen gnome-screenshot -w`
Grab an area: `screen gnome-screenshot -a`
Send the grab to the clipboard: `gnome-screenshot -c`
Interactive: `gnome-screenshot -i`

---

You can set the directory with the [dconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dconf.1.html) command.

#### Command line

In this example I'm going to set my **Downloads** directory.

```
dconf write /org/gnome/gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory \'/home/youruser/Downloads\'
```

Please put the full path to the folder... My case ***/home/virtual/Downloads***

#### GUI with [dconf-editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-editor) [image: Install dconf-editor]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but does not work for me.

Comment: @frozen-flame... if you run "gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory". what is the result?

Comment: After `gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory /new/path`, `gsettings get org.gnome.gnome-screenshot auto-save-directory` gives me `/new/path`. But when I take screenshot with `Print Scr` button, the picture still saves to the old path(`~/Pictures`).

Comment: @frozen-flame: edited for dconf -  do you have a value in last-save-directory?

Comment: @frozen-flame: also try a shot using shift-PrtScr to select an area (this is what I tested above for working)

Comment: @frozen-flame: Also you can check in the gnome-control-center > keyboard > shortcuts.. and see if you have a key to "Save a screenshot to Pictures" ... and disable it.

Comment: Same issue here. I tried settings both `auto-save-director` and `last-save-directory`. Independent which screenshot method I use it does not land in the select folder.

Comment: @RomanRaguet Not found.

Comment: @frozen-flame: you can check my edit to see if helps.

Comment: @RomanRaguet Great answer! A little bit inconvenient, but the problem solved. I just wonder if we can change the command binding of `keyboard->screenshots` from `gnome-settings-daemon media-keys` to `gnome-screenshot`?

Comment: @RomanRaguet Do you know where are the keyboard settings stored? A config file somewhere?

Comment: @frozen-flame: the keyboard setting are in the schema org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys . but i think you need to set a custom shortcut to trigger gnome-screenshot.

Comment: @frozen-flame: but you can disable the default print shortcut. and then create a new custom one to launch gnome-screeshot and assign the print key.

Comment: Is there a way to change how it names the file?

Comment: "screen gnome-screenshot -w", "screen gnome-screenshot -a", didn't work for me, it worked with "gnome-screenshot -w", "gnome-screenshot -a".

Answer (score 3):

Just install dconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Open dconf-editor and edit the `auto-save-directory` field (see screenshot below):

- `org` > `gnome` > `gnome-screenshot`

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yeah, that doesnt work with the printscreen screenshot.

Comment: it does work for me (ubuntu 16.04)